# How do I specify a variable number of OR values in a Doctrine SQL Where

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How do I programatically create a Doctrine ORM call for the following SQL when I have a different number of values in the 'OR' clause on each run?

```
   SELECT * FROM table1
   WHERE table1.group = 1 OR 2 OR 3
```

Specifically, I may only want to get table1.group values of 1 OR 2 next time

Comment: `WHERE table1.group IN (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @Linger, sorry, I am looking for the Doctrine code where I can pass in varable number of values for the OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values can be in array. Sample repository method:

```
public function findAllInGroupList(Array $groupList)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $queryText  = "SELECT a FROM AcmeBundle:Acme a ";
    $queryText .= "WHERE a.group IN (:groupList)";

    $query = $em->createQuery($queryText);
    $query->setParameter('groupList', $groups);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```